# Topological sort for longest path in DAG?

Tags: java, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an unweighted DAG, and I am trying to find the length of the longest path from any vertex in my graph. I found this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/

But it seems to be more focused on a weighted graph. How would I go about modifying that code to work for an unweighted graph so I could just find the integer value of the length of the longest path?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about modifying that code to work for an unweighted graph so I could just find the integer value of the length of the longest path?

You can think of your graph as a weighted DAG, where each edge has a weight of 1 unit.

Comment: I'm just not super sure how the dist[] part works in the code on that site. I don't understand why the distances are set to INF and how they update.

Comment: Because I'm just getting INF for all of the distances besides the source

Comment: The dist array stores the largest distance from the source vertex v to all vertices u in the graph, at any given point in the algorithm. All entries dist[i], i ≠ v, start out as negative infinity, because they need to be updated the first time we find a path from v to the corresponding vertices, which has length > 0. The demo figure used in the article is very descriptive of the steps followed and it's worth inspecting, if you haven't done so already. Also, make sure you're not initializing the dist entries to INF, but to _negative_ INF.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! That description helped me understand what was happening a lot more. I got it to work, and it's definitely faster than depth first search but still pretty slow, do you know of any way to speed up the mapping of each path? I was thinking dynamic programming, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Chanege this line

```
int getWeight() { return weight; }
```

to

```
int getWeight() { return 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about the longest path ***from*** a `src` node to any node in the graph and not ***to***, a `dfs` would suffice. But if you want to know the longest path ***from*** a `src` node ***to*** every other node (Here we care about the `dest` node which made the longest path), then we need to use the topological ordering of the graph.

In this case, since we only need to find the longest directed path in a graph, we can start a `dfs` from each node to find the longest path from that node. One optimization we can do is since can be many paths that can pass through node `X`. We only calculate the longest path from `X` once and then memoize the value, so that the next time we visit the node `X` we return the already computed value. In this way, we compute subproblems only once.

The optimal substructure property is like this. Let's assume `dp[src]` is longest directed path ***from*** `src` node then

```
for each neighbor of src node :
    dp[src] = Math.max(dp[src], weight(src->neighbor) + dp[neighbor])
```

For an unweighted graph, we can assume, weight to be `1`. Once we found the longest path from all nodes, the maximum of them will be the answer. Below is the implementation using `DFS` and `memoization`. The Graph is built based on your property that given an input array of length `n`, there exists a directed `edge` from `arr[i]` to `arr[j]` such that `arr[i] < arr[j]` and `i < j` and `0 <= i, j < n`. `getLongestPathOfGraph()` returns the longest directed path of the graph

```
class Graph {
    Map<Integer, List<int[]>> adjList;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> longestPaths;
    int longestPath;

    public Graph(int[] nodes) {
        adjList = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            adjList.put(nodes[i], new ArrayList<>());
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nodes.length; j++) {
                if (nodes[i] < nodes[j]) {
                    addEdge(nodes[i], nodes[j], 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addEdge(int src, int dst, int weight) {
        adjList.get(src).add(new int[]{dst, weight});
    }

    public int getMaxLength(int src) {
        // Checking if the longest Path is computed from src node, if yes returning the already computed result.
        if (longestPaths.get(src) != 0) return longestPaths.get(src);
        int len = 0;
        for (int[] neighbor : adjList.get(src)) {
            len = Math.max(len, neighbor[1] + getMaxLength(neighbor[0]));
        }
        longestPaths.put(src, len);
        return len;
    }

    public void getLongestPathOfGraph() {
        longestPath = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        longestPaths = new HashMap<>();
        for (int key : adjList.keySet()) longestPaths.put(key, 0);
        for (int src : adjList.keySet()) {
            if (longestPaths.get(src) == 0)
                longestPaths.put(src, getMaxLength(src));
            longestPath = Math.max(longestPath, longestPaths.get(src));
        }
        System.out.println("Longest Path = " + longestPath);
    }
}
```